# How to shave off last character using sed?

Tags: regex, shell, string, sed

That is, going from `ABCD` -> `ABC`

Answer (score 74):

You can try:

```
sed s'/.$//'
```

The regex used is `.$`

- `.` is a regex meta char to match
  anything (except newline)
- `$` is the end of line anchor.

By using the `$` we force the `.` to match the last char

This will remove the last char, be it anything:

```
$ echo ABCD | sed s'/.$//'
ABC
$ echo ABCD1 | sed s'/.$//'
ABCD
```

But if you want to remove the last char, only if its an alphabet, you can do:

```
$ echo ABCD | sed s'/[a-zA-Z]$//'
ABC
$ echo ABCD1 | sed s'/[a-zA-Z]$//'
ABCD1
```

Answer (score 12):

you don't have call external commands if you are using a shell, eg bash/ksh

```
s="ABCD"
echo ${s/%?/}
```

Comment: A related bash solution `echo ${s:0:-1}`, which specifies the index of the first character you want (`0` for the beginning) and the index of the last character you want, where a minus sign makes the index count relative to the end (`-1` for the second-to-last character).