# Incorrectly deleting last characters from file

Tags: python, sed, subprocess, truncate

Within my subprocess, I want to remove the last 4 characters from every line in my txt file. However the lines are of varying length. I've seen a lot of pages including [How to shave off last character using sed?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3675169/how-to-shave-off-last-character-using-sed) but nothing seems to be doing it correctly. I have about 100 lines and the first 38 don't remove the first 4 characters properly. A seemingly random number is removed. After those first lines, all lines after have my expected output. How? For now I have:

```
subprocess.run(['sed', 's/.\{4\}$//', 'infile.txt'])
```

The file always has four useless characters at the end - **/pid**:

```
3726-weinberg/pid
11717-christopher/pid
11138-span/pid
.
.
.
2932-smith/pid
.
.
.
```

The problem is that the output is:

```
3726-w
11717-chri
111
.
.
.
2932-smith //line 39! all good now
.
.
.
```

but I expected:

```
3726-weinberg
11717-christopher
11138-span
.
.
.
2932-smith //line 39! all good now
.
.
.
```

Sed need not be the solution. If truncate or cut or any various other options work too feel free to let me know. I chose sed because I use it in another part of the program.

Comment: Please add sample input (no descriptions, no images, no links) and your desired output for that sample input to your question (no comment).

Comment: I have executed your exact python code with your exact input and it works. Also, in your description, it is not a "seemingly random number removed", your test output says that for the first lines, the last 11 characters are removed instead of 4.

Comment: Please specify which version of *Python* you're running.

Comment: @thanasisp - You don't get the output that I got? Why would that be? I dont understand

Comment: contactme8359 yes it works. Probably you have to provide more so that you get an answer. Maybe the whole input file, the environment you run it, etc. Probably it is not a code issue.

Comment: Also please show the output of `file -i infile.txt`.

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps it's easier to do this in python.

```py
with open('infile.txt', 'r') as f:
    lines = f.read()
out = [line[:-4] for line in lines.split('\n')]
with open('infile.txt', 'w') as f:
    f.write('\n'.join(out))
```

Answer (score 2):

Is it because you have lines that are only three characters or less long? Your current subprocess will only remove the last four characters if the line is at least four characters long. If that is the problem, the following small change will work (this seems to work for the input I have tested):

```py
subprocess.run(['sed', 's/.\{1,4\}$//', 'infile.txt'])
```

Comment: No it's not because my lines are less than four characters. My lines are about 10-15 characters long and sed is deleting much more than it should be. Not sure why. Updating the post to reflect what I mean.

Answer (score 1):

This link may be helful. [Remove last two characters from each line.](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/386564/remove-last-two-characters-from-each-line)

```
sed 's/....$//' filename
```

Here each dot '.' represents the character and $ read the character from the end of line